# How to use Cadence/Temporal versioning API( workflow.getVersion) in a loop

Tags: cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

Imagine this workflow of 10 activities in a loop:

```java
public class LoopWorkflowImpl implements LoopWorkflow{
   private final Api api = Workflow.newActivityStub(Api.class, ...)

   @override
   public int start(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
             sum += api.getCount();
        }
        return sum;
   }
}
```

How can I change `api.getCount()` to `api.getCountV2()` for existing workflows?

E.g. if there is workflow already completed 5 activities with `api.getCount()`, how can let let it use `api.getCountV2()` for the rest 5 activities?

Answer (score 3):

### Correct Way to apply new behavior for old and new workflow

This is what you should do -- using the versioning API with changeId for each iteration:

```java
public class LoopWorkflowImpl implements LoopWorkflow{
   private final Api api = Workflow.newActivityStub(Api.class, ...)

   @override
   public int start(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
             int version = Workflow.getVersion("useV2API"+i, Workflow.DEFAULT_VERSION, 1)
             if( version == 1){
                 sum += api.getCountV2();
             }else{
                 sum += api.getCount();
             }
        }
        return sum;
   }
}
```

### Below will only apply for new workflows

Many people will do this instead and it won't work for the existing workflow

```java
public class LoopWorkflowImpl implements LoopWorkflow{
   private final Api api = Workflow.newActivityStub(Api.class, ...)

   @override
   public int start(){
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
             int version = Workflow.getVersion("useV2API", Workflow.DEFAULT_VERSION, 1)
             if( version == 1){
                 sum += api.getCountV2();
             }else{
                 sum += api.getCount();
             }
        }
        return sum;
   }
}
```

### Why

This is because of an important contract of `Workflow.getVersion()` API --

The return value from the API for the same changeId is immutable once returned. This is guaranteed with or without the version is being written into history using MarkerRecord event.

So in the 2nd solution , on the first iteration, `Workflow.getVersion()` will returns `Workflow.DEFAULT_VERSION`(-1) as there is no version marker during replay. So in the rest iteration, it will always return `Workflow.DEFAULT_VERSION`.

The best way to fix is to include the iteration Id into the changeId. Using the different changeId will allow the versioning to pick different version for different iteration.

If you are worried about this will create too many version marker events in the history, you can combine this solution with the [global versioning pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941723/what-is-a-good-way-pattern-to-use-temporal-cadence-versioning-api) to only do this for old workflows:

```java
public class LoopWorkflowImpl implements LoopWorkflow{
   private final Api api = Workflow.newActivityStub(Api.class, ...)
   private GlovalVersionProvider globalVersionProvider = GlobalVersionProvider.get();

   @override
   public int start(){
        if (globalVersionProvider.isAfterVersionOfUsingGlobalVersion()) {
            GlobalVersionProvider.upsertGlobalVersionSearchAttribute();
        }
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
             if (globalVersionProvider.isAfterVersionOfUsingV2Api()) {
                 sum += api.getCountV2();
             }else{
                 int version = Workflow.getVersion("useV2API"+i, Workflow.DEFAULT_VERSION, 1)
                if( version == 1){
                    sum += api.getCountV2();
                }else{
                    sum += api.getCount();
                }
             } 
        }
        return sum;
   }
}
```

So the the versioning marker with iteration index is only applying for existing old workflow executions.

Comment: Great write-up. I would point out that both ways are "correct". But it is up to the application developer to decide which one he needs in his particular case. I've seen use cases when all branches of a loop had to be versioned together and other use cases that needed only new iterations of the loop taking a new code path.

Comment: This is on the assumption of changing the behavior for both existing and new workflows. I think even if developers want to just change for the whole loop , it will look more straightforward to version the whole loop instead of just do it within the loop

Comment: Your comment is useful too since most people may just read the title of the question. I just made a update to make it more clear

Comment: @LongQuanzheng why can just call `Workflow.getVersion` before the loop then using the returned version inside the loop to determine which `getCountV1` or `getCountV2` should be called?

Comment: @LongQuanzheng, I understood my previous comment after rereading the question `if there is workflow already completed 5 activities with api.getCount(), how can let let it use api.getCountV2() for the rest 5 activities?`. If it is ok call `api.getCountV2()` for 5 already completed activities, can I leave `Workflow.getVersion` outside the loop?

Comment: Using versioning outside of the loop will do the same as the 2nd solution in “ Below will only apply for new workflows” — only new workflows will use the v2 API.

Comment: > If it is ok call api.getCountV2() for 5 already completed activities   —— Sorry l don’t understand this statement. How can you let completes activities use v2?

Comment: Thank you @LongQuanzheng and sorry for my late repy because I didn't get notifications.
>  If it is ok call api.getCountV2() for 5 already completed activities
This is silly statement since I misunderstood Cadence.